# Visual studio closed after the start, when try open unity script

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i trying to open any script directly from unity with visual studio, it opens for few second (i even see some code) and then closing, without any error messages or something like that.

I can run solution, which unity create in root folder, it works, but i do not understand why i cant run it directly (double click on script in unity GUI).

I using Unity 5 and VS2013 Premium with Resharper last version (licence).

In projects, which dont have common with unity it works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with VS2015 (with resharper). I haven't bothered to try to fix it yet, but [it seems to be an ongoing issue](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/note-to-other-visual-studio-users-upgrading-to-unity-5-2.353542/). (Thread picked at random, this looks like something that's happened often in the history of Unity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me often after leaving Unity open over night.  I usually just follow these steps to fix the problem:

> 1. Close VS.
> 2. Close Unity.
> 3. Open Unity.
> 4. In Unity select Visual Studio Tools/Generate Project Files.

After that, I can then open my script files in Visual Studio by double clicking on them in Unity.